# no permission to rake db migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, deployment, rake, digital-ocean

I am trying to launch my app on a digital ocean server and I am almost to the final steps of deployment.  bundler works fine, my gems are updated, but when I run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:259:in `rescue in lock': There was an error while trying to write to Gemfile.lock. It is likely that  (Bundler::InstallError)
you need to allow write permissions for the file at path: 
/home/rails/HandCo-op/Gemfile.lock
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:244:in `lock'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:34:in `lock'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.4/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:94:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.4/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:124:in `check'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.4/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:131:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.4/lib/rubygems_executable_plugin.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `block in run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:10:in `<main>'
```

I see that it wants me to add permissions to gemfile.lock and I will look into that next.  Does anyone have any advice regarding this issue? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This is the line I used to fix the issue, just make sure you are above or in the app dir!

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) myappfolder
```

YAY!